# Why is there multiple clicks on div, using jQuery 3.5.1

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The application is a web page intended to be run on a phone. I have a checkbox on a row and allow users to tap anywhere on the row to change the setting. This worked fine until I upgraded from jQuery 3.3.1 to 3.5.1.

```
<li>
    <div id="main_zone_power" class="nav-toggle-item">
        <span>Power</span>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            <span class="switch_track round" tabindex="0"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
```

A click on a row generates a change on the checkbox. A message is sent to a remote device. The old library generated one click; the new one generates hundreds, causing a stack overflow.

```
$("#main_zone_power").on("click", function(e){
    $("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]").click();
});
$("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(e){
    var value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    send_and_query_command(get_zone_command(COMMAND.Z_POW, zone_number), value);
});
```

The application receives a reply from the remote device and updates the checkbox.

```
main_zone_page.update_UI_power = function(value) {
    $("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', value);
}
```

What is the best way to cause a single click to be generated?
I have tried to disable both controls with some success.

Comment: `$("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]")` is a collection of Elements. Why get it twice, by the way? Just put it in a variable and reuse.

Comment: preventdefault and stoppropagation might be useful. Or settimeout?

Comment: Try changing `$("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]").click();` to `$("#main_zone_power input[type=checkbox]").focus();`?

Comment: I would create a function in this case so that you could call the function from the click or call it programatically. Generating clicks is highly inefficient and just adds confuseion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some executable code. Adding `e.stopPropagation()` does not affect the response. Each click on the `div` produces two **click** actions and one **change** action. Changing jquery to 3.5.1 produces hundreds of **click** actions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .cone {background-color: yellow; height:80px; }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var acount = 0;
  var rcount = 0;
  $("#one").on("click", function(e) {
    acount++;
    console.log("click " + acount);
    $("#action").text(acount);
    $("#cbone").click();
  });
  $("#cbone").on("change", function(e) {
    rcount++;
    console.log("change " + rcount);
    $("#reaction").text(rcount);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="one" class="cone">
  <span>Property</span>
  <label id="action">Action</label>
  <input id="cbone" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <label id="reaction">Reaction</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```